# Display previous logged in timestamp from txt file

Tags: php, html

I was asked to do this by my college staffs so kindly help me out with this! I have a php file with a text box and login id is supposed to be entered in it and login button is to be pressed. Once this button is pressed, the login id and timestamp is stored in a txt file. Next time the same login id is used then the timestamp is to be overwritten. I have done this part successfully. Now, i wanna display the timestamp before overwritting it. This is something similar to last seen of whatsapp. How can i display it?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Login Portal</title></head>
<body><center>
<h1>TPF EMPLOYEE LOGIN</h1><hr><br><br>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $myfile = file_get_contents('data.txt');
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['id'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $txt=$_SESSION['name'].",".$date.",\n";
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    if(preg_match("/$name/", $myfile))
    {
        $results = preg_replace("/$name.*\,/", $txt, $myfile);
        file_put_contents('data.txt', $results);
    }
    else
        {
            file_put_contents('data.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<form name='login' method='post'>";
    echo "Enter your login id : <input type='text' name='id' id='id' /><br><br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />";
    echo "</form>";
    }
?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the contents of my txt file:

```
a,2014-10-05 19:00:40,

b,2014-10-05 19:00:31,
```

Using the comma after the name as an identifier how do i display the previous timestamp before overwritting it?

Comment: why not just utilize mysql tables for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if(preg_match("/$name/", $myfile))
{
```

to include $matches and alter the regexp, then work with $matches array:

```
if(preg_match("/$name\,(.*),/", $myfile, $matches))
{       
   echo 'Previous Login: ' . $matches[1];
```

Example: http://ideone.com/1diNNd

Hints: use a db, ensure $name is unique...

Comment: Using db i know to do easily! This is a problem assigned to me by my staffs so have to do according to their say!!